# Iterator of associative container is not dependent on Comparator template argument

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2013, stl, iterator

The Compiler is not able to diffrentiate between iterators of two different type.

See the two types here.

```
typedef std::set<int, std::greater<int> >             PriceBookBuy;
typedef std::set<int, std::less<int> >                PriceBookSell;

typedef PriceBookBuy::iterator PriceBookBuyIter;
typedef PriceBookSell::iterator PriceBookSellIter;
```

I want to overload a template method based on the two iterator types.

```
class LVOrderBookBin
{
    int a;
    int b;
    public:

   template<typename PriceBookBuy>
   void erasePriceLevel(std::vector<PriceBookBuyIter> remover) throw()
   {
            b++;
            remover.begin();
        }
        template<typename PriceBookSell>
        void erasePriceLevel(std::vector<PriceBookSellIter> remover) throw()
        {
            a++;
            remover.begin();
        }
};
```

A typical usage:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector< PriceBookBuyIter> vecBuy(3);
    std::vector< PriceBookSellIter> vecSell(3);


    LVOrderBookBin lv;
    lv.erasePriceLevel<PriceBookBuy>(vecBuy);
    lv.erasePriceLevel<PriceBookSell>(vecBuy);
}
```

Same code used to work with Vs2008, but does not compile with VS2013. It does not compile with gcc also.

error: ‘template void LVOrderBookBin::erasePriceLevel(std::vector, std::allocator > >)’ cannot be overloaded

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work".

Comment: I mean it doesn't compile. error: ‘template<class PriceBookSell> void LVOrderBookBin::erasePriceLevel(std::vector<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<PriceLevelHolder>, std::allocator<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<PriceLevelHolder> > >)’ cannot be overloaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library implementations are well within their rights to do this, and it was nearly made mandatory. The effect you're seeing is known as SCARY iterators and it's a good thing.

You would have to wrap the iterator in a custom struct- effectively tag them with your own custom type to use OR in this way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards SCARY iterators. I found this on MSDN.    http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/04/06/10291485.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct way to specialize templates; you are just declaring function overloads. You need to specialize like this:

```
class LVOrderBookBin
{
public: 
    template<typename T>
    void erasePriceLevel(std::vector<typename T::iterator> remover) throw();
};

template<>
void LVOrderBookBin::erasePriceLevel<PriceBookBuy>
     (std::vector<PriceBookBuyIter> remover) throw()
{
    //...
}
template<>
void LVOrderBookBin::erasePriceLevel<PriceBookSell>
     (std::vector<PriceBookSellIter> remover) throw()
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I am overloading, not specializing. 

I have tried the code as you mentioned also. But the approaches are not working. As PriceBookBuyIter and PriceBookSellIter are same type as per compiler.

Comment: [Works](https://ideone.com/mEya3Y) for the example you posted, but you need to specify the template arguments explicitly.

Comment: which compiler are you using? 
I used gcc version 4.4.7 20120313  and VS2013 compiler. It used to work for me in Vs2008.

Comment: That link is gcc version 4.9.2.